# Ubuntu running on Virtual Box shows black screen

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have two VMs installed on Virtual Box. And both of them are Ubuntu.
But one of them shows black screen upon booting, the login page is not shown. It was totally fine before.

How can I solve this problem?

I have really important file inside it so I need to get it back.

Is there anything I can do to get back the file from virtual hard disk ?

Answer (score 2):

> I have two VMs installed on Virtual Box. And both of them are Ubuntu.
>   But one of them shows black screen upon booting, the login page is not
>   shown. It was totally fine before.

#### Don’t panic!

I’ve had this happen to me sporadically at times when launching an Ubuntu Guest OS on VirtualBox. Never understood why it happens, but it always cleared up for me if I just right-clicked on that problematic Ubuntu Guest OS in the VirtualBox application and then selected, “Close -> Power Off”; see screenshot below:

[image]

Yes, that is the equivalent of a hard power off/unplugging on a real world machine, but in my experience when that black screen happens the guest OS machine never even got to the most basic level of booting anyway. So this is not a big deal or a risk.

Once that is done, restart the Ubuntu Guest OS and try again. It should work fine.